# How to get all non .NET framework assemblies in AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to find all assemblies in the current AppDomain, which are not part of the .NET framework (which means that they are either my own libraries or 3rd party libraries).

Is there any easier way to do it than hard-coding all the .NET Framework's assemblies names to my code and finding all Assemblies from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` which doesn't match any of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Task));
        CustomAttributeData attributeData = a.CustomAttributes.First(attribute => attribute.AttributeType == typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute));
        string value = attributeData.ConstructorArguments[0].Value as string;
```

And the value will be Microsoft® .NET Framework

Comment: Thanks, this was a great solution! I will still wait if anyone gives a better answer, but if not, I will accept this!

Comment: Also: Some of the assemblies had a value of "Microsoft® Visual Studio", but I'm pretty sure that happens only when debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: For some of assemblies, the attribute will be "Microsoft ASP.NET Core MVC" or "Microsoft .NET Extensions" or "Microsoft ASP.NET Core", so we can exclude assemblies that start with "Microsoft"

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] dotNetPaths=new string[]{"/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/","/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/"};
var otherAssemblies=AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                             .GetAssemblies()
                             .Where(x=>!dotNetPaths.Any(y=>x.CodeBase.Contains(y)));
```